# Format partition with GParted to recover Windows after installing Ubuntu over it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a broken Ubuntu OS.  I have tried many a ways to restore/recover the hard drive.  Boot-repair, Windows recovery, Ubuntu live usb repair disc option.... nothing is working.

The 750gb partition that is shown was where Ubuntu was previously installed in place of my Windows installation.  Yes that is right, I installed Ubuntu over Windows instead of the dual booting option like a fool.  Let us move past that.

Right now I want to format my partitions so as to repair my Windows OS and then install Ubuntu as a dual boot.  Please step by step or semi-detailed instructions in using GParted or possibly the terminal.  I'd appreciate any help offered and I thank you in advance!

[image: partitions]

Comment: Again i'm not sure if i made this clear, I want to format partitions in a way that I can use a Windows recovery USB/Disc to reinstall/repair Windows so that I may do a clean reinstall and after getting windows fully situated I will install Ubuntu at a later date.  I know this sounds like blasphemy but I do intend to come back to Ubuntu so as to breathe free air once more.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you installed Ubuntu over Windows, you automatically erased Windows. So, it is gone and unrecoverable. You will have to reinstall Windows if you want to use it again.

Second, it is recommended to install Ubuntu on a ext4 partition, not fat or ntfs partition. You could install it on Windows-type partition (under non-standard conditions), but it works best on linux-type (ext) partitions.

The recommended way to install a dual-boot system is to first install Windows automatically (it creates some 3-4 partitions) and then install Ubuntu. Just remember: in a dual-boot environment GRUB (the Ubuntu bootloader) will supersede the Windows bootloader. If you remove Ubuntu at a later time, you will have to repair the Windows bootloader.

Keep in mind that Windows can't deal with linux partitions. Just clean-erase the entire hard-disk for now and let Windows do its' work.

Ubuntu  typically uses 2 partitions: ext4 (>10GB) and swap (= 1,5...2xRAM size).

Comment: " It does install and works on Windows-type partition" since when? Ubuntu -must- be installed on a POSIX supported filesystem.

Comment: No rinzwind I was installed using a USB installer created with rufus as the ubuntu website instructed. Thank you ipse! I have already gotten to a good place accidentally and ironically enough.  I had tried every option in the live USB to fix my ubuntu os. 1. Run normal os 2. Advanced startup options. 3-6. Were .efi type options which could not find the image and the final option 7. Startup options brought me to a list.    The list I was ignoring for the most part had (1. Disk info 2. Diagnostics 3. Boot options and 4. Continue booting OS)  after running all diagnostics my USB was a success :)

Comment: For help to others I couldn't install world of Warcraft which was a silly but I'm sure relatively common problem which led to my dismay, I have to get to bed for work but I will be posting a guide on getting wow/battlenet working fully tomorrow! Thank you all for your help and advice, even you Karen :) you were the most smug response but helpful nonetheless, tbh you should be on an English language forum xD your editing of grammar was magical.